# Proper use of nav-item class in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Using the examples from the documentation, I am noticing that when I inspect my nav bar, .nav-item doesn't actually do anything (as in, the class doesn't show up in the console)...

This isn't a huge thing as I can write my own styles in that class. I am just curious why it's there? Is it supposed to (or did it used to) do something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for navigation on the bootstrap website. What you have said above about `nav-item` is mostly true. Most of the time the `nav-item` class is not used by bootstrap. However in some navigation examples it is used:

- [Tabs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#tabs) use `nav-item` to bump down the items in the list with `margin-bottom: -1px`
- [Fill](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#fill-and-justify) uses `nav-item` to make sure each of the items fill the width

Using the `nav-item` class allows developers to quickly change between different types of navigation in the bootstrap system while only changing the wrapping class on the `<ul>`. This becomes more powerful when you generate the navigation you now only need to change the type of navigation in one location.

Comment: I have been looking at the source code since I posted the question (guess I should have started there), and I see what you are saying. nav-item seems to be a subclass (if that is the correct terminology - I am a backend developer and relatively new to UX)... thanks for the answer.